# Transit visa for Frankfurt for Indian national on h1b I797A

Tags: lufthansa, h1b-visas, frankfurt

My change of status from F1 to H1b was recently approved and I have I797A with me. My F1 visa stamped in my passport is still valid and I am going to home country(India) to get the H1b stamping done. 
I have Lufthansa flight with 4 hour layover in Frankfurt. Do I need a transit visa for my case?
(I do see my flights are arriving and departing in the same terminal)